# how can I change the permissions of a linux socket file?

Tags: c, sockets, permissions

I have a program which creates a socket, and then I want to change the permissions of the socket file:

```
ret_val = chmod(filename, 0777);
```

, but it doesn't change, even though ret_val will be 0. If I try the same thing on a regular file, it works.

Any ideas?

P.S: I am running the program as root, so it has all the authority needed.

Comment: I too am having this problem.  On my desktop Ubuntu 10.04, changing permissions to 777 on the directory where the socket file is located did the trick.  On an identical install (sane DVD) on my test machine, nothing I do about the directory's permissions has any effect on the created socket file's permissions.  THey remain srwxr-xr-x.  I tried using the chmod() function and a system() call to set the file perms to 777.  No luck.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From `man 7 unix`:

> In the Linux implementation, sockets which are visible in the file system
>   honor the permissions of the directory they are in.   Their  owner,
>   group  and  their permissions can be changed.  Creation of a new socket
>   will fail if the process does not have write and search (execute)  permission  on  the directory the socket is created in.  Connecting to the
>   socket object requires read/write permission.   This  behavior  differs
>   from  many BSD-derived systems which ignore permissions for UNIX domain
>   sockets.  Portable programs should not rely on this feature  for  security.

So if you want to control permissions on a socket, in order to be portable, you should instead control the permissions of the directory containing the socket.

Comment: @anna lear  Sorry about the bad answer.  My firefox decided i didn't need to access this posting so I could delete it.  Dropped something on the keyboard and got this lovely post as a reward.  Then I couldn't access it.

Comment: On Linux, though, you can make it a lot safer by first doing a `fchmod(socket, 0600)` then use `chmod()` after the bind (once the file exists). [See details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781134/change-linux-socket-file-permissions/74329441#74329441).

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42955529/1425297

"If you want your socket world-writeable, the easiest way would be for you app to call this before your socket is created and bound: umask(0);"