# change linux socket file permissions

Tags: c++, sockets, unix-socket

First, yes this is related to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977556/how-can-i-change-the-permissions-of-a-linux-socket-file), but I'm having a slightly different set of circumstances and my post there is not getting an answer.

So, on my Dell desktop workstation, Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit, I have developed a server program that is designed to offer a Unix-Domain socket to a PHP "program" run by Apache.  (note:  umask = 0022) I named the socket file /home/wmiller/ACT/web_socket_file.  (ACT is a reference to the product name).  /home/wmiller/ACT has permissions of 777.  /home/wmiller/ACT/web_socket_file gets created with permissions of 777.

Now, I copy the program to my test platform, a Q7 format Intel processor board, which also has Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit and umask = 0022.  Same directories, same 777 permission on the dir.  However, now when i run the code /home/wmiller/ACT/web_socket_file comes up with 755 permissions and Apache/PHP can't open the Unix Domain socket because it gets r-x permissions instead of rw- or rwx.  Apache is running in uid = www-data.

```
sockaddr_un       webServAddr;
remove( g_webSocketFileName.c_str() );       // to erase any lingering file from last time

memset(&webServAddr, 0, sizeof(webServAddr));
webServAddr.sun_family        = AF_UNIX;
snprintf( webServAddr.sun_path, UNIX_PATH_MAX, "%s", g_webSocketFileName.c_str() );

if (( g_webServerSock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
{
    PLOG( ERROR ) << "Failed to acquire the web Server socket: ";  // uses google glog tool
    return -1;
}
```

So I tried both of these and neither worked.

```
chmod( g_webSocketFileName.c_str(), S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG  | S_IRWXO );
```

and

```
char temp[100];
sprintf( temp , "chmod o+w %s\n", g_webSocketFileName.c_str() );
system( temp );
```

Tried permissions of 777 and o+w.

I even tried adding a

```
unlink( g_webSocketFileName.c_str() );
```

But no help there.

Anyone have suggestions on why ir works on one machine and not on another almost identical machine?
Would I be better off to put the socket file elsewhere?  Is there a standard place-where-socket-files-go?

Comment: Got it!

All I had to do was move the chmod() after the bind() statement and it works!.

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, you need to call `fchmod()` on the Unix domain socket file descriptor *before* `bind()`.  In this way the `bind()` call will create the filesystem object with the specified permissions.  Calling `fchmod()` on an already bound socket is not effective.

Using `chmod()` could lead to [TOCTTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOCTTOU) race condition.  If possible, use `fchmod()` instead.

This is a Linux-specific hack.  On most BSD systems, `fchmod()` will fail on a socket fd and set `EINVAL`.

---

*Edit.*  I found this system-dependent behavior difference by tinkering.  Perhaps the best "source" for this should be the kernel source code itself.

- On FreeBSD, it appears that `fchmod()` on a Unix domain socket is defined as a no-op that sets `EINVAL` [(Ref1)](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/sys_socket.c#L85)
- On Linux, it appears that a Unix domain socket fd is created just like an inode, along with file modes (but with `S_IFSOCK` bitwise-or'ed in). [(Ref2)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c#L540)  Linux's `fchmod()` implementation will then happily apply changes to such an object.  When binding a Unix domain socket to an address, the file modes are used in creating the filesystem-object. [(Ref3)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/unix/af_unix.c#L857)  According to `man 2 stat`, `S_IFSOCK` is present in POSIX.1-2001.

If I read the sources wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Do you have an authorative source for this working on linux? In the manpage (fchmod(3), while fchmod(2) doesn’t talk at all about sockets), the behaviour is described as unspecified.

Comment: I have tested fchmod() on Linux. None of the combinations (before bind, after listen) worked. In all cases it returned 0 but did not change the file permissions. Only chmod() worked.

Comment: @Meixner I added my own answer. The issue is that the `umask()` is still being applied so you need both: the `fchmod()` before the `bind()` in case the permissions are to be more restrictive than what the defaults would otherwise be and call `chmod()` after the `bind()` to finalize the permission/mode.

Answer (score 1):

As Cong Ma said, under Linux you should look at using `fchmod()` before the `bind()`. However, the `umask()` is still going to be applied. So the correct sequence goes like this:

```
// create the socket
int s = socket();

// restrict permissions
#ifdef __linux__
fchmod(s, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
#endif

// bind the socket now
bind(s, &u, sizeof(u));

// finally, fix the permissions to your liking
chmod(u.sun_path, 0666);  // <- change 0666 to what your permissions
```

*Important Note: the code here does not show the error handling which **is required** to make sure things work as expected. See complete example here.*

What is the problem with `fchmod()`?

If you try to set the exact mode that you need in `fchmod()`, the file gets created by `bind()` and at that point the `umask` gets applied. That means with a `umask` such as `022`, you still do not get the write permissions for the group and other users (i.e. you would get `0644` instead of `0666`).

One way to use `fchmod()` and skip on the `chmod()` after the `bind()` is to change `umask` with:

```
umask(0);
bind(...);
```

However, if like many of us you are running in a multithreaded application, changing the `umask` is probably not an option. The solution above works without having to use `umask(0)` which long term is a better way of doing things.