# How to create Unix Domain Socket with a specific permissions in C?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, unix-socket, umask

I have a simple code, like:

```
sockaddr_un address;
address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(address.sun_path, path);
unlink(path);

int fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(fd, (sockaddr*)(&address), sizeof(address));
listen(fd, 100);
```

I want to **atomically** create the Unix Domain Socket file with a specific permissions, say: `0777`. The manual doesn't say anything about socket file permissions with regard to `umask` or whatever. Even, if the `umask` does affect the socket file, then it's not an atomic way - in multi-threaded program.

I hope, there is a way to achieve my goal without using synchronization of `umask()` calls.

Comment: Why care?  Setting permissions after the fact has never caused an issue for me.  It's not like there are processes sitting there waiting to pounce illegitimately on your socket -- and if there are, you have far bigger problems than socket permissions.

Comment: You do not need to worry so much about atomically setting permissions.  If there's a rogue process trying that hard to access the socket, that they could get to it between the microsecond you create it and the microsecond you set permissions on it, then your machine is compromised, and you should be fixing that rather than trying to work around it.

Comment: @cHao: There may be the processes that are listening `inotify` and may try to connect to the socket before my process has set right permissions - it's a "good" process, but it will fail. My question is more the theoretical question, that an attemp to find workaround for some specific situation.

Comment: Well, the `umask` `bind` method, if it worked, could be made thread-safe, you would only need to `fork` and then `umask` `bind` and then pass the FD for the opened socket back to the parent.

Comment: @DanD.: .. or protect access to the `umask();bind();umask()` triple using a mutex.

Comment: @alk That wouldn't work as that mutex would have to block all the other threads and there is no way to do that without having that mutex be used at every system call that either effects or is effected by the umask.

Comment: @cHao: Ever heard of multiuser systems? Like unix? Like in one of the keywords of this question? If an application *doesn't* handle a process waiting to pounce illegitimately on it's socket the application is **severely** broken.

Comment: @Marcus: If you have such a process, your **machine** is severely broken.  You can be as paranoid as you want, but at some point you have to trust the machine you're running on, and the people who run it. It's actually not a huge step from "what if there's a rogue process?" to "what if the kernel is compromised?". That way lies madness and/or solipsism.

Comment: @cHao: If no malicious user has gained root access **and** the kernel does not contain any privilege escalation security holes you can be sure the kernel is not compromised, which is exactly my point. By *not* trusting processes running as another user on the same machine you prevent malicious processes from getting root access.

Comment: @Marcus: No, in fact, you don't do a whole lot. There are like a half dozen other security sins you have to commit before a socket's permissions are even remotely an issue. If you're that paranoid, for example, then you're already not running as a privileged user anyway. But in any case, sockets can't be connected to before they're `listen`ing, so permissions aren't critical til then.

Comment: @cHao: The last part is a good point - setting permissions between bind() and listen() should be sufficient.

Comment: I would like to use this comment chain as a teachable moment for any SO contributors that might benefit from it: do not waste four comments convincing many security-conscious readers that you're willfully wrongly dismissive of how a loss of any bit of security matters (because defense-in-depth is weakened by any and all situations where people go "well, we don't add thickness here, the other layers got it covered") just go directly to dropping the crucial wisdom of how the maximum security can be trivially achieved anyway.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Another solution is to create a directory with the desired permissions, and then create the socket inside it (example code without any regard for error checking and buffer overflows):

```
// Create a directory with the proper permissions
mkdir(path, 0700);
// Append the name of the socket
strcat(path, "/socket_name");

// Create the socket normally
sockaddr_un address;
address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(address.sun_path, path);
int fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(fd, (sockaddr*)(&address), sizeof(address));
listen(fd, 100);
```

Comment: It's the best proposed solution, since the ownership of a parent directory of the unix-socket affects its connect-ability.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Parent dir is 777, socket is still 755, so only writable by the owner.

Comment: That could be because there was a typo in the mode. I've edited the response with the correct answer.

Answer (score 17):

I had the best luck using `chmod()` (NOT `fchmod()`) using the file name for the unix domain socket after calling `socket()`, `bind()`, but, before calling `listen()`.

```
  int return_value;
  const char *sock_path;
  struct sockaddr_un local;

  sock_path = "/tmp/mysocket";

  sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sockfd == -1)
  {
    perror("socket");
    exit(-1);
  }

  local.sun_family = AF_UNIX; 
  strcpy(local.sun_path, sock_path);
  unlink(local.sun_path);
  len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len);

  chmod(sock_path, 0777);

  retval = listen(sockfd, BACKLOG);
  if (retval == -1)
  {
    perror("listen");
    exit(-1);
  }
```

. . . . .

Comment: It doesn't work, if some process monitors the socket via `inotify` - as I mentioned in a comment to my question.

Comment: @abyss.7 Actually I just tested (Linux 3.8.0) and it does work.  connect() will fail on a socket if listen() has not been called yet.  So, it would seem you can safely chmod a socket before calling listen() without worry that an un-authorized user will connect.  However, as Elias mentioned, it is best to create a directory with the desired permissions and the socket within the directory.

Comment: Another method: create the file with another filename, chmod() and then rename() to the final file name.

I usually create the file with -TMP appended, then rename after chmod() and listen()

Answer (score 8):

Forking, using `umask` and passing back the `fd` is the only portable way I can think of. Having a directory for the socket is better in any case, for example nobody can delete the socket if the directory doesn't have the proper permissions, and creating directories can be done atomically.

The bigger problem is that relying on permissions is not portable - many BSD-derived socket stacks simply ignore the permissions of enclosing directories and/or the socket itself.

On GNU/Linux systems, you can do it by calling `fchmod()` on the socket `fd` after `socket()` and before `bind()`.

Comment: Exactly, fchmod() before bind() works without races in a multi-threaded environments, but is not portable to, let's say, some *BSD variants.  Even POSIX says that fchmod() on socket has unspecified behaviour.  You definitely *should* care about the permissions being set atomically.

Comment: What does "forking and passing the fd back" mean?

Comment: @Guido You can pass file descriptors through a socket.  See http://www.normalesup.org/~george/comp/libancillary/

Comment: @Anonymous Can't you just create the socket, fork, umask, bind, and then return 0 to tell the parent the socket is ready?  Easier than ancillary data...  And do you know for sure which BSDs ignore permissions?  Best info I can find is that 4.2 ignored socket perms, but checked dir perms.

Comment: I'm also curious about BSD ignoring permissions. Nothing i've read so far supports what you say about them being ignored on the parent directory, and it works correctly on OSX 10.10.1 at least.

Comment: Note that `fchmod()` works great if applying less permissions. If you want more, you may still be hit by the `umask(0022)` (or whatever other value you might have). In that case, you need both `fchmod()` before the `bind()` and then `chmod()` after to add permissions that `umask()` may have removed. [See here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781134/change-linux-socket-file-permissions/74329441#74329441).