# How to connect to a socket created by a root process from a non root process

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tizen

I have a process that is running with root privileges[server]
and a client which is an app process[non root].
I need to communicate b/w these two, the IPC is unix domain sockets.

The problem is that the connection from the client fails with access denied error.

Is there a way to make this communication possible.

I am working on tizen platform, which has SMACK access rules as well, but i  believe that i have added all the SMACK permit rules that can come in way of the communication.
But the file level permission denial for the client process is not allowing to connection.

Is there any way to do IPC in this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember that local sockets are files in the file-system. The clients needs to be able to read and write these "files".

Comment: You need to adjust the `umask` of the creating process such that others will have read write access to the socket path.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31619445/694576, if not a duplicate.